# Domdocument removing base64 image

Tags: php, image, base64, domdocument

When I process an image in base64 format using DOMDocument() it doesn't output the image:

```
$text ='<p>Some text and then an image...<br><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" data-filename="avatar.png" style="width: 400px;"><br></p>';

//Prepare a DOM so we can make changes to the html
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); 

//Clean up empty paragraphs
$paragraphs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach ($paragraphs as $item)
{
    if (!trim($item->textContent))
    {
        $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
    }
}

//Save changes to the html
$text=$dom->saveHTML();

echo $text;
```

How do I get it to process this image?

Comment: your code works for me:- http://prntscr.com/avvtff   so i am unable to get what problem you are facing?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you have a different version or something :(

Comment: No errors, no image either

Comment: I think im going to just try and write something to save these images in S3 because storing in the database is just nuts anyway...

Comment: try with blob datatype if you want to put it into db